# Symfony Get "GET"

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've got the following route:

```
register_invitecode:
  url:     /register/:invitecode
  param:   { module: home, action: register }
register:
  url:     /register
  param:   { module: home, action: register }
```

I want to use the "invitecode" in a partial, **_form.php** but I can't get the $_GET['invitecode']. I've used the following code:

```
<?php echo $sf_request->getGetParameter('invitecode') ?>
```

It doesn't give me any error, but it also doesn't show me the invitecode.

What can I do?

Also, is there any way to avoid the double declaration of the "register" route? *invitecode* should be an optional parameter, not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Get parameters (`sfWebRequest->getGetParameter()`) are the parameters that are the "physical" parameters of the HTTP GET operation. In a HTTP GET all parameters are added to the querystring (`?invitecode=abcd`).
If you want to access the parameters from the routing (like in your case), you have to use the `sfWebRequest->getParameter()`.

Comment: Thanks. `$request->getParameter('invitecode')` worked in template.

Answer (score 2):

as far as register and register_invitecode are the same actions you can use 1 route

```
register:
  url:     /register/:invitecode
  param:   { module: home, action: register }
```

to generate a link with invitecode try `<?php echo url_for('register?invitecode=foobar'); ?>` without `<?php echo url_for('register'); ?>`

to get the variable in the template try `<?php echo $sf_request->get('invitecode'); ?>`

in the action `$request->getParameter('invitecode')`

Comment: This won't match if there's no invitecode in the url. You need to add a default value in the param object, like `invitecode: dummy`, so a simple `/register` would match. In the action, check if the invitecode is the default (and invalid) value, and do the appropriate steps.

Comment: `Call to undefined method sfWebRequest::get.` I had to use getParameter() instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to force the route to be GET you may add this to your route:

```
requirements:
    sf_method: [get]
```